# using theming to adjust theme in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, faces, themes

I'm trying to use [theming](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bthemes/theming) to make adjustments to an existing theme. Under `dotspacemacs/user-init` I have the following section:

```
  (setq-default theming-modifications
        '((tao-yang
           (font-lock-comment-face :foreground "#bbbbbb")
           (org-level-1 :foreground "#ea056d")
           (org-level-3 :weight 'normal)
           (default :cursor "pink")
           (cursor :background "pink")
           )))
```

- The font-lock-comment and org-level-1 adjustments work just fine.
- `:weight 'normal` gives an error: `set-face-attribute: Wrong type argument: symbolp, (quote normal)`
- I also get a wrong argument error when I try `:slant 'italic`
- The last two lines don't create errors but also neither has an impact on the cursor color, individually or combined

I'm a bit at a loss of why that is. I couldn't find anything in the documentation of theming that would send me in the right direction.

How can I adjust the weight or slant of a font using theming in spacemacs?